# "Spreading out" locally free sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, curves-and-surfaces

Let $Y$ be a regular surface flat, projective over $R$, where $R$ is complete DVR. Let $X$ be the generic fiber and $F$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. We know that if the rank of $F$ is $1$ then we can find a line bundle $F'$ on $Y$ such that it restricts to $F$ on $X$. The question is if the rank of $F$ is greater than $1$, does this still hold true i.e., can we find a vector bundle $F'$ on $Y$ such that when restricted to $X$ we get back $F$? (It seems to me that the answer should be yes by the use of EGA $\mbox{IV}_3, 8.5.2(ii)$ and $8.5.5$, but I am not totally sure) One can assume that the generic fiber is smooth if necessary.

Comment: Sure. Take a coherent extension of F to Y and then take the double dual. Since you are on a surface, reflexive sheaves are locally free.

Comment: @Hoobler: Thank you for the comment. I am not able to locate the result that the reflexive sheaf on a surface is locally free. I have found this result on smooth surfaces. Does it also hold for regular surfaces? Could you please suggest a reference

Comment: The argument goes like this: If $M$ is a reflexive module over a $2$-dim regular local ring, then $depth(M)=2$. Now use Auslander-Buchsbaum-Serre to conclude that the projective dim $pd(M) = 2-depth(M) =0$.